# Combine three Pandas Pivot Tables with different column numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three pandas pivot_tables:

```
# First Pivot Table

# Total Sales of Product 1
Month
Branch    1       2       3
1        100.00   80.00  50.00 
2        200.00   50.00  60.00
3        250.00   90.00  65.00 

# Second Pivot Table

# Total Commission of Product 1
Month
Branch    1       2       3
1        10.00   8.00  5.00 
2        20.00   5.00  6.00
3        25.00   9.00  6.50

# Third Pivot Table

# Sales Count (general including other products)
Month
Branch    2     3
1         5     5 
2         1     6
3         3     6
```

when I try combine the three pivoted dataframes, I'm getting the error: `"cannot convert float NaN to integer"`.

The command I tried:

```
dfResult = dfTotalSales.append(dfCommission).append(dfSalesCount)
```

Besides the error above...

How can I combine them and return a new column with the average of Net Sales total?

```
Formula: (Total Sales - Commission) / Sales account
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

is your data is like the following
in branch 1 first month sales is 100
in branch 2 first month sales is 80

if yes than I think sales count is not present for the branch 1.
i. e. according to my understanding the sales count is given only for branch 2 and 3.

so while processing he tried to fill null value, but other than sales count the data is integer. so it can not convert the float to int.

so make all in int or float then try.

Comment: Thanks Anuprita!

The understand is correct... I'm new with python and pandas... could you please tell me how to do it? Thanks once more and all the best!

Comment: the line "dfResult = dfTotalSales.append(dfCommission).append(dfSalesCount)" is not giving me any error. Please explain the result you want. i created these dataframe and run that line.

Comment: Is the dataframe that you created pivot_table? I believe this problem is only happening with pivot_tables...